# How to append elements into a dictionary in Swift?

Tags: swift, nsdictionary

I have a simple Dictionary which is defined like:

```
var dict : NSDictionary = [ 1 : "abc", 2 : "cde"]
```

Now I want to add an element into this dictionary: `3 : "efg"`

How can I append `3 : "efg"` into this existing dictionary?

Comment: use NSMutableDictionary

Comment: Are you sure you want a dictionary and not an array, since your keys seem to be the numbers 1, 2 and 3?

Answer (score 289, accepted):

You're using `NSDictionary`. Unless you explicitly need it to be that type for some reason, I recommend using a Swift dictionary.

You can pass a Swift dictionary to any function expecting `NSDictionary` without any extra work, because `Dictionary<>` and `NSDictionary` seamlessly bridge to each other. The advantage of the native Swift way is that the dictionary uses generic types, so if you define it with `Int` as the key and `String` as the value, you cannot mistakenly use keys and values of different types. (The compiler checks the types on your behalf.)

Based on what I see in your code, your dictionary uses `Int` as the key and `String` as the value. To create an instance and add an item at a later time you can use this code:

```
var dict = [1: "abc", 2: "cde"] // dict is of type Dictionary<Int, String>
dict[3] = "efg"
```

If you later need to assign it to a variable of `NSDictionary` type, just do an explicit cast:

```
let nsDict = dict as! NSDictionary
```

And, as mentioned earlier, if you want to pass it to a function expecting `NSDictionary`, pass it as-is without any cast or conversion.

Comment: Thanks for a proper explanation of what a person should actually do. Utilizing the convenience of Swift to create and manipulate a `Dictionary` object and then converting it to `NSDictionary` at the end if you need to. Wonderful. Thanks.

Comment: Is there anyway that I can append to the same key using a delimiter (similar to [addValue](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsmutableurlrequest/1407676-addvalue)). I mean like *add* a `"Antonio"` to key `1` so  `dic[1]` would return `"abc, Antonio"`.

Comment: @honey not that I am aware of... but it's a simple append if the element already exists

Answer (score 143):

you can add using the following way and change `Dictionary` to `NSMutableDictionary`

```
dict["key"] = "value"
```

Comment: I got an error which says `Cannot assign to the result of this expression`

Comment: add this way for your question dict[3] = "efg";

Comment: check my edited answer its working for me.change dictionary to Mutable one it works!

Comment: `dict["testval"] = "test"`.. Error `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`

Comment: It won't work with 2.2+ , dict is readonly in that expression

Comment: So update an element and add a new element is same grammar in Swift `dict["key"] = "value"`.

Comment: Thanks it helped instead of using "key" I have used variable key

Answer (score 89):

I know this might be coming very late, but it may prove useful to someone.
So for appending key value pairs to dictionaries in swift, you can use **updateValue(value: , forKey: )** method as follows :

```
var dict = [ 1 : "abc", 2 : "cde"]
dict.updateValue("efg", forKey: 3)
print(dict)
```

Comment: Thank you! I kept getting something about a missing default parameter when I was trying to add new values to the dict. This method worked.

Answer (score 64):

**SWIFT 3 - XCODE 8.1**

```
var dictionary =  [Int:String]() 

dictionary.updateValue(value: "Hola", forKey: 1)
dictionary.updateValue(value: "Hello", forKey: 2)
dictionary.updateValue(value: "Aloha", forKey: 3)
```

So, your dictionary contains:

dictionary[1: Hola, 2: Hello, 3: Aloha]

Comment: How is this better than `dictionary[1] = "Hola"`?

Comment: Is simply another way to do it. All depend of what do you need do ! I my case, this is the best way

Comment: I understand that you think this is better; that's why you posted it. But I don't see how this is better. Please, tell me how this is better

Comment: I agree there should be a method called "addValue" or "setValue", that "updateValue" should be used for UPDATING as its name says

Comment: The reason is that when the dictionary was init be has a value [] that is different to nil, so is necessary use the property updateValue because we are trying change the value and not insert it.

Comment: updateValue Apple docs: `If the value of an existing key is updated, updateValue(_:forKey:) returns the original value. If the given key is not present in the dictionary, this method adds the key-value pair and returns nil.` That's how you can check if the key was already present. So in the current example this makes no sense.

Comment: not sure why this is so upvoted. this is not an answer

Answer (score 23):

If your dictionary is `Int` to `String` you can do simply:

```
dict[3] = "efg"
```

If you mean adding elements to the *value* of the dictionary a possible solution:

```
var dict = Dictionary<String, Array<Int>>()

dict["key"]! += [1]
dict["key"]!.append(1)
dict["key"]?.append(1)
```

Answer (score 19):

**Swift 3+**

Example to assign new values to Dictionary. You need to declare it as NSMutableDictionary:

```
var myDictionary: NSMutableDictionary = [:]
let newValue = 1
myDictionary["newKey"] = newValue
print(myDictionary)
```

Answer (score 14):

```
For whoever reading this for swift 5.1+

  // 1. Using updateValue to update the given key or add new if doesn't exist


    var dictionary = [Int:String]()    
    dictionary.updateValue("egf", forKey: 3)



 // 2. Using a dictionary[key]

    var dictionary = [Int:String]()    
    dictionary[key] = "value"



 // 3. Using subscript and mutating append for the value

    var dictionary = [Int:[String]]()

    dictionary[key, default: ["val"]].append("value")
```

Answer (score 12):

In Swift, if you are using **NSDictionary**, you can use `setValue`:

```
dict.setValue("value", forKey: "key")
```

Comment: edited your answer, in the future consider adding more info to avoid downvotes.

Answer (score 12):

Given two dictionaries as below:

```
var dic1 = ["a": 1, "c": 2]
var dic2 = ["e": 3, "f": 4]
```

Here is how you can add all the items from **dic2** to **dic1**:

```
dic2.forEach {
   dic1[$0.key] = $0.value
}
```

Comment: It's better to use `.forEach` instead of `.map` as we don't need any return mapped array

Comment: To be more clear, this can be `dic2.map { dic1[$0.key] = $0.value }`

Answer (score 12):

**[String:Any]**

For the fellows using `[String:Any]` instead of `Dictionary` below is the extension

```
extension Dictionary where Key == String, Value == Any {
    
    mutating func append(anotherDict:[String:Any]) {
        for (key, value) in anotherDict {
            self.updateValue(value, forKey: key)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 11):

`Dict.updateValue` updates value for existing key from dictionary or adds new new key-value pair if key does not exists.

Example-

```
var caseStatusParams: [String: AnyObject] = ["userId" : UserDefault.userID ]
caseStatusParams.updateValue("Hello" as AnyObject, forKey: "otherNotes")
```

Result-

```
▿  : 2 elements
    - key : "userId"
    - value : 866
▿  : 2 elements
    - key : "otherNotes"
    - value : "Hello"
```

Answer (score 11):

As of Swift 5, the following code collection works.

```
 // main dict to start with
 var myDict : Dictionary = [ 1 : "abc", 2 : "cde"]

 // dict(s) to be added to main dict
 let myDictToMergeWith : Dictionary = [ 5 : "l m n"]
 let myDictUpdated : Dictionary = [ 5 : "lmn"]
 let myDictToBeMapped : Dictionary = [ 6 : "opq"]

 myDict[3]="fgh"
 myDict.updateValue("ijk", forKey: 4)

 myDict.merge(myDictToMergeWith){(current, _) in current}
 print(myDict)

 myDict.merge(myDictUpdated){(_, new) in new}
 print(myDict)

 myDictToBeMapped.map {
     myDict[$0.0] = $0.1
 }
 print(myDict)
```

Comment: This is the most exhaustive answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

To add new elements just set:

```
listParameters["your parameter"] = value
```

Answer (score 8):

There is no function to append the data in dictionary. You just assign the value against new key in existing dictionary. it will automatically add value to the dictionary.

```
var param  = ["Name":"Aloha","user" : "Aloha 2"]
param["questions"] = "Are you mine?"
print(param)
```

The output will be like

["Name":"Aloha","user" : "Aloha 2","questions" : ""Are you mine"?"]

Answer (score 5):

To append a new key-value pair to a dictionary you simply have to set the value for the key. for eg.

```
// Initialize the Dictionary
var dict = ["name": "John", "surname": "Doe"]
 
// Add a new key with a value

dict["email"] = "john.doe@email.com"

print(dict)
```

Output -> `["surname": "Doe", "name": "John", "email": "john.doe@email.com"]`

Answer (score 3):

```
var dict = ["name": "Samira", "surname": "Sami"]
// Add a new enter code herekey with a value
dict["email"] = "sample@email.com"
print(dict)
```

Comment: Please provide some information why this answer solves the problem

Comment: @StephenReindl If you run it, you'll see ;)

Answer (score 0):

Up till now the best way I have found to append data to a dictionary by using one of the higher order functions of Swift i.e. "reduce". Follow below code snippet:

```
newDictionary = oldDictionary.reduce(*newDictionary*) { r, e in var r = r; r[e.0] = e.1; return r }
```

@[Dharmesh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4085910/dharmesh-kheni) In your case, it will be,

```
newDictionary = dict.reduce([3 : "efg"]) { r, e in var r = r; r[e.0] = e.1; return r }
```

Please let me know if you find any issues in using above syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Swift 5 happy coding

```
var tempDicData = NSMutableDictionary()

for temp in answerList {
    tempDicData.setValue("your value", forKey: "your key")
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I added Dictionary extension

```
extension Dictionary {   
  func cloneWith(_ dict: [Key: Value]) -> [Key: Value] {
    var result = self
    dict.forEach { key, value in result[key] = value }
    return result  
  }
}
```

you can use `cloneWith` like this

```
 newDictionary = dict.reduce([3 : "efg"]) { r, e in r.cloneWith(e) }
```

Comment: You don't need to clone a dictionary. Dictionary is a value type in Swift.

Answer (score -11):

if you want to modify or update NSDictionary then 
first of all typecast it as NSMutableDictionary

```
let newdictionary = NSDictionary as NSMutableDictionary
```

then simply use

```
 newdictionary.setValue(value: AnyObject?, forKey: String)
```