# swift ios append elements to array

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, xcode, append

I have an array that looks like this:

```
var parameters: [String: AnyObject] = [
            "title": "something",
            "type": "1"
        ]
```

How do I append something like this:

**"someNewField": "someValue"**

So that the array would end up like:

```
   parameters: [String: AnyObject] = [
                "title": "something",
                "type": "1",
                "someNewField": "someValue"
            ]
```

Comment: This might be a use-case better suited for Structs, just by judging from the Dictionary keys.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a dictionary not an array. To append something new to it you would do something like this:

```
parameters["someNewField"] = "someValue"
```

Here you can find more documentation on arrays, dictionaries, and their differences:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/CollectionTypes.html

Also this is a possible duplicate of:

[How to append elements into dictionary in swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27313242/how-to-append-elements-into-dictionary-in-swift)