# Why am I am getting an "Invalid (non-string) key in JSON dictionary" error message?

Tags: json, swift, document

I am trying to use Swift to create a reference to an image and storing it in documents using a dictionary and JSON. I believe that I created the correct syntax for dictionary based on [another SO answer that I found](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41040987/4035833). The error message below happens when I press the button with function `addButtonClicked`. What am i doing wrong?

Error message:

> Invalid (non-string) key in JSON dictionary

```
// Inside UICollectionViewCell 
var representedAssetIdentifier: String? = nil

// Inside  UIViewController
  var count: Int = 0
  var dictionary: [Int:String] = [:]

  @objc func addButtonClicked() {        
      do {
          let fileURL = try FileManager.default
              .url(for: .applicationSupportDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: true)
              .appendingPathComponent("example.json")
          
          try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: dictionary).write(to: fileURL)
      } catch {
          print("Error report: \(error.localizedDescription)")
      }
      let newViewController = PickerTest3()
      self.navigationController?.pushViewController(newViewController, animated: true)
  }

  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
      if let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as? ImageCell {
          let newCount = count
          dictionary.updateValue(cell.representedAssetIdentifier!, forKey: newCount)
          count += 1
          selectedCells.append(indexPath)
          cell.index = selectedCells.count
      }
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

The error message is pretty clear. You can not create a JSON string using a dictionary that has integer keys. You need to use strings.

Note: Not related to your question but you should not write any file directly to the application support directory:

> Use this directory to store all app data files except those associated with the user’s documents. For example, you might use this directory to store app-created data files, configuration files, templates, or other fixed or modifiable resources that are managed by the app. An app might use this directory to store a modifiable copy of resources contained initially in the app’s bundle. A game might use this directory to store new levels purchased by the user and downloaded from a server.
> All content in this directory should be placed in a custom subdirectory whose name is that of your app’s bundle identifier or your company.
> In iOS, the contents of this directory are backed up by iTunes and iCloud.

[File System Basics](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html)

Comment: That is what I thought the error message was saying, but in the link that I posted with my OP there are numerous examples of people using the [Int:String] combination. How are they able to do it?

Comment: You can create a dictionary in Swift with any key that conforms to `Hashable` protocol but you can not create a JSON from it unless you convert the keys from `Int` to `String`. I would also add a character prefix such as `"k1"`, `"k2"` and so on.